# How To Toggle The cell Colour And Text In A TStringGrid On And Off

Tags: lazarus, tstringgrid, text-rendering

I am running Lazarus v0.9.30 (32 bit compiler).

I have a TForm with a standard TStringGrid on it.  The grid has the following properties set.  RowCount = 5, ColumnCount = 5, FixedCols = 0, FixedRows = 0.

I Googled some [code](http://www.festra.com/wwwboard/messages/12892.html) that showed me how to change the cell colour and add some text to the cell when a user clicks on a TStringGrid cell.  All works fine and I have extended it slightly to toggle the color/text on and off on the GridClick event.

The questions I have are more to better understand the purpose behind some of the elements of the code.

There is an array of Foregroud (FG) and Background (BG) TColor objects.  Are they there to store the cell color attributes that are set on the GridClick event, so if the DrawCell event needs to get triggered again for any reason the cell can redraw itself?  Can you avoid using the array of TColors and just set the colour / text in the DrawCell event as required?

If you need to use the arrays, I would assume that dimensions must match the Grid.ColCount and Grid.RowCount (ie. set via the SetLength call in Form.Create)

Is there a way to detect that you are clicking outside of the 5 x 5 cells of the  stringgrid (ie in the whitespace) and thus prevent the GridClick from calling the DrawCell event.  No matter where you click you always get a valid value for Row and Col.

```
unit testunit;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs,
  ExtCtrls, Menus, ComCtrls, Buttons, Grids, StdCtrls, Windows, Variants,
  LCLType;
type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Grid: TStringGrid;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure GridClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure GridDrawCell(Sender: TObject; aCol, aRow: Integer;
      aRect: TRect; aState: TGridDrawState);
  end; 

var
  Form1: TForm1; 

implementation

var
  FG: array of array of TColor;
  BG: array of array of TColor;

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Col, Row: integer;
begin
  // Set the sizes of the arrays
  SetLength(FG, 5, 5);
  SetLength(BG, 5, 5);

  // Initialize with default colors
  for Col := 0 to Grid.ColCount - 1 do begin
    for Row := 0 to Grid.RowCount - 1 do begin
      FG[Col, Row] := clBlack;
      BG[Col, Row] := clWhite;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.GridDrawCell(Sender: TObject; aCol, aRow: Integer;
  aRect: TRect; aState: TGridDrawState);
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := Grid.Cells[ACol, ARow];

  // Fill rectangle with colour
  Grid.Canvas.Brush.Color := BG[ACol, ARow];
  Grid.Canvas.FillRect(aRect);

  // Next, draw the text in the rectangle
  Grid.Canvas.Font.Color := FG[ACol, ARow];
  Grid.Canvas.TextOut(aRect.Left + 22, aRect.Top + 2, S);
end;

procedure TForm1.GridClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Col, Row: integer;
begin
  Col := Grid.Col;
  Row := Grid.Row;

  // Set the cell color and text to be displayed
  if (Grid.Cells[Col,Row] <> 'Yes') then
    begin
      BG[Col, Row] := rgb(131, 245, 44);
      FG[Col, Row] := RGB(0, 0, 0);
      Grid.Cells[Col, Row] := 'Yes'
    end {if}
  else
    begin
      BG[Col, Row] := rgb(255, 255, 255);
      FG[Col, Row] := RGB(255, 255, 255);
      Grid.Cells[Col, Row] := '';
    end; {else}
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the [`AllowOutboundEvents`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/grids/tcustomgrid.allowoutboundevents.html) to `False`, the [`OnClick`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/controls/tcontrol.onclick.html) event will be fired only when you click on a certain cell, not when you click on a whitespace. So if you use this property, you will always get valid cell coordinates when you click somewhere.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StringGrid1.AllowOutboundEvents := False;
  ...
end;
```

Another point is that you should use the [`OnPrepareCanvas`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/grids/tcustomgrid.onpreparecanvas.html) event instead of `OnDrawCell`, because in `OnDrawCell` you would have to paint everything, including text rendering. With [`OnPrepareCanvas`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/grids/tcustomgrid.onpreparecanvas.html) you just set the [`Brush.Color`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/graphics/tbrush.color.html) and [`Font.Color`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/graphics/tfont.color.html) for each cell which is going to be rendered.

And, you don't need to use arrays, you can use the [`Objects`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/grids/tcustomstringgrid.objects.html) like you did with your columns, but surely you can keep the colors in the arrays. In the following example I've used the [`Objects`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/grids/tcustomstringgrid.objects.html) and there's also shown the usage of the [`OnPrepareCanvas`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/grids/tcustomgrid.onpreparecanvas.html) event, but note that this example as well as yours from the question colorize all cells including the fixed ones:

```
type
  TCellData = class(TObject)
  private
    FStateYes: Boolean;
    FForeground: TColor;
    FBackground: TColor;
  public
    property StateYes: Boolean read FStateYes write FStateYes;
    property Foreground: TColor read FForeground write FForeground;
    property Background: TColor read FBackground write FBackground;
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Col, Row: Integer;
  CellData: TCellData;
begin
  for Col := 0 to StringGrid1.ColCount - 1 do
    for Row := 0 to StringGrid1.RowCount - 1 do
    begin
      CellData := TCellData.Create;
      CellData.StateYes := False;
      CellData.Foreground := clBlack;
      CellData.Background := clWhite;
      StringGrid1.Objects[Col, Row] := CellData;
    end;
  StringGrid1.AllowOutboundEvents := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
var
  Col, Row: Integer;
begin
  for Col := 0 to StringGrid1.ColCount - 1 do
    for Row := 0 to StringGrid1.RowCount - 1 do
      StringGrid1.Objects[Col, Row].Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.StringGrid1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Col, Row: Integer;
  CellData: TCellData;
begin
  Col := StringGrid1.Col;
  Row := StringGrid1.Row;

  if StringGrid1.Objects[Col, Row] is TCellData then
  begin
    CellData := TCellData(StringGrid1.Objects[Col, Row]);
    if CellData.StateYes then
    begin
      StringGrid1.Cells[Col, Row] := '';
      CellData.StateYes := False;
      CellData.Foreground := RGB(255, 255, 255);
      CellData.Background := RGB(255, 255, 255);
    end
    else
    begin
      StringGrid1.Cells[Col, Row] := 'Yes';
      CellData.StateYes := True;
      CellData.Foreground := RGB(0, 0, 0);
      CellData.Background := RGB(131, 245, 44);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.StringGrid1PrepareCanvas(sender: TObject; aCol, aRow: Integer;
  aState: TGridDrawState);
var
  CellData: TCellData;
begin
  if StringGrid1.Objects[ACol, ARow] is TCellData then
  begin
    CellData := TCellData(StringGrid1.Objects[ACol, ARow]);
    StringGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := CellData.Background;
    StringGrid1.Canvas.Font.Color := CellData.Foreground;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by use TCustomStringGrid objects?  The writer of the code has multidimensional arrays to store TColors.....how does using TCustomStringGrid help me?

Comment: Sorry for misleading you. Fixed and added some other hints and example.

Comment: Ok....I see what you are doing.....I was planning to load every cell with an object....I just need to add the TColor properties as I have a property which is like 'StateYes'.  A question: You didn't use the grids DrawCell event to paint the cell like in this answer? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701462/delphi-how-can-i-change-color-of-a-cell-in-string-grid)

Comment: Yeah, because Delphi has no `OnPrepareCanvas`, they have just `OnDrawCell` where, as you can see in that post have to render also the text itself. If you want just to modify the canvas properties for the cell to be rendered, like the background or font color, then the `OnPrepareCanvas` is the right stage. About the `StateYes`, you can use the `Yes` string comparing of course, but if you would like to change it e.g. to `Yeah` in the future, you would have to change it on more than one place :-)